# Is there an opposite of python matplotlib tight_layout method?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am having trouble with a heatmap plot which is generated using seaborn package and my code looks like:

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Frequency', index = ['Hour'], columns = ['Rank'])
ax = sns.heatmap(piv, square = True, cmap = 'rocket_r')
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
ax.figure.savefig("results/timing.png")
plt.close()
```

The output of this code does not look like what I want. As you can see, the y axis looks compressed and so the values are not readable:

[image]

I have already tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 15))
```

which did not solve the problem. So I am wondering if there is a method which could automatically find the best fit of axis of a plot. Thanks.

Comment: "The output of this code does not look like what I want" -- which is what exactly?

Comment: @Denziloe edited the question. basically trying to have a better looking y axis

Comment: Are you aware of manual axis methods? The solution must be automatic?

Comment: @Denziloe manual axis method would work too.

Comment: Would `ax.set_aspect("auto")` suit your needs?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, tried it and worked like a charm. Might want to post it as the answer.

Comment: Feel free to answer yourself, or mark as duplicate of any similar question where this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who stumbled upon this question while looking for something similar, found the answer in the comments:

`ax.set_aspect("auto")` works